# Node.JS promise then add scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Is there a nicer way to do the following in Node.JS using a promise:

```
var y = "...";

promise.using(getDatabaseConnection() function(connection) {
  return connection
    .query("some sql")
    .then(function(result) {callAnotherFunction(result, y);}
    .catch(function(error) {callAnotherFunction(error, y);}
});
```

This works, but is a bit clunky looking/hard to read.  I have tried:

```
.then(callAnotherFunction.bind(null, y))
```

As suggested in another SO post and

```
.then(callAnotherFunction(y))
```

Just hoping for a really simple solution, but neither worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can set it up like this:

```
const callAnotherFunction = function(y) {
 return function(result) {
   console.log('y',y);
   console.log('result',result);
   return 'something'
 }
}

promise.using(getDatabaseConnection() function(connection) {
  return connection
    .query("some sql")
    .then(callAnotherFunction(y))
    .catch(callAnotherFunction(y))
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I see you're using `Promise.using` here so assuming bluebird, also going to assume modern Node:

```
async function whatever(y = "...") {
  await promise.using(getDatabaseConnection(), async conn => {
    try { // try/catch outside the using depending on whether the handling
          // requires the connection or not
      callAnotherFunction(await conn.query("some sql"), y); 
    } catch (e) {
      callAnotherFunction(e, y);
    }
  }); 
}
```

Although, the function should just return a promise for the results, rather than call a continuation since it is more composable this way.

Comment: I am using 6.10.3 LTS so I don't think that async is supported :(, otherwise this would have been perfect!